# Check if a table item doesn't exist. How to check returned 'Items' array if empty? Javascript/DynamoDB

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, is-empty

I am trying to see if an item exists in the DynamoDB database. However I can't find a straight forward answer. So I am using the `getItem()` operation.

This returns a JSON. In the documentation it says that the Item returned should be empty if no item was found in the database. However, I can't seem to figure out how to check if this returned value is empty. I have tried variations of `if(data == "undefined"){`

```
//PutItem - DynamoDB table: check if group exists
                var dynamodb5 = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: AWS.config.region });
                var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
                var params = {
                      Key: {
                       "groupName": {
                         S: groupname
                        }
                      }, 
                      TableName: "group"
                     };
                dynamodb5.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                     alert("This group doesnt exist.")
                }else{
                   // successful response console.log(data); 


                    if(data.Items[0] == "undefined"){
                        console.log("ITS WORKING");
                    }
```

}

Comment: won't `data.Items.length === 0` work here?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this already. However, as jarmod pointed out I used `Items` instead of just `Item`. Maybe this was my issue. `length` was coming back as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getItem` response doesn't include `Items`, it includes `Item` (see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property)). It will return one item, if there is an item with the given key, or no item.

You can detect this as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const params = {
  Key: {
    'groupName': {
      S: groupname,
    },
  },
  TableName: 'group',
};

ddb.getItem(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else if (data.Item) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    console.log('Success, but no item');
  }
});
```

Minor note: there's little reason to use `var` now that we have `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to add:

`Item` is for GetItem, `Items` is for Query.

Also AWS documentation mentions `ResourceNotFoundException` "for the operation that tried to access a nonexistent table or index". To avoid the confusion:

- Getting a non-existing item will return `undefined` on the Item
- Trying to get something from non-existing table or non-existing index will cause that error. For example you mistype the table name or the primary index.